# Is there a way to override [BeforeScenario] in Specflow C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, hook, specflow

**Background:** At my work place, we have a generic Selenium test automation framework that's used by various teams. It's a skeleton framework on top of which each team customizes/adapts the test automation framework to suit their needs. So, it's kind of tightly coupled and doesn't give a lot of wiggling room to make changes.

**Problem:** This framework initializes selenium webdriver for each scenario within `[BeforeScenario]` hook. So, if I have a test with 100 scenarios under [Examples], webdriver gets initialized 100 times. This has a couple of major drawbacks:

1. It makes the tests execution slow
2. I can't run tests doesn't necessarily need a fresh webdriver instance. So, for example if I've initialized the  webdriver and logged into my application in my previous scenario to test a feature, I don't need to re-login for my next scenario to test a different part of the same feature.
3. I can't add Browser Capabilities since the webdriver gets initialized when the hook gets called, which is part of the library I don't have access to.

However, since the webdriver gets initialized for every scenario, I lose my last login state. So, I want to initialize the webdriver only once per test run. So, I'm thinking of implementing this in `[BeforeRun]` hook. * Is it even possible?

- Can I override `[BeforeScenario]` hook with `[BeforeRun]` hook?
- Are there any other alternatives to the solution I'm thinking of?
- Is there a way to override the webdriver initialized in the base class library from a locally initialized webdriver?

**What I've tried:** I've spoken to the person in my organization who maintains this  test automation framework to provide a way for teams to be able to make changes or enable it to parameterize some areas. However, it's not looking like it's going to be happening anytime soon, since it's an organization wife change, it needs a lot of approvals.

Comment: Without seeing enough code to provide an answer there is no way we can help you. There might be some C# object-oriented gymnastics that you could do, but we need to see some code.

Comment: Just throwing this out but I ran a specflow scenario before that only initialized the browser once per feature.  All test cases used the same browser and the first step of the test was to go to the default url and the last step was to logout (if I was logged in).  If memory serves, I was using BeforeFeature/AfterFeature to initialize the browser and AfterFeature for the teardown.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the responsible for your test automation framework to adapt it, but you can adapt the way you use Specflow to this rigid requirements. I.e., take those tests that can run without the need for re-login again and group them together under one scenario.

This defeats the purpose of using Specflow in the first place, but again reusing a webdriver or any other component across different scenarios doesn't seem to be a good practice either, because you want your tests to be isolated as much as posible.